# Base Converter in Python

Tags: python

I am writing a program to convert in any base to base 10 in Python. The code for the program is shown below.

```
print("Enter the number you want to convert to base 10: ")
number = input()
"""length of the digit entered"""
length = len(number)
print("Enter the base of the number: ")
base = input()

for i in range(len(number)):
    length = length - 1
    """Computes the sum for each digit"""
    s = number[i] * (int(base) ^ length) 
    s += s
print(s)
```

The problem is that for any number I enter the answer is always 1111. Any advice on how to fix this issue will be welcome.

Comment: Use `raw_input` and `enumerate(number[::-1])`

Comment: @Dabrion `raw_input` is obsolete in python 3. Don't recommend it to new programmers.

Comment: @simonzack fair enough, should be flagged python3 in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`^` is the [bitwise XOR operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations), not the power operator. In Python the [power operator is `**`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator):

```
s = number[i] * (int(base) ** length)
```

There are other mistakes too; `s += s` is simply `s *= 2`, you are doubling the number there. You probably want to start with `s = 0` *outside* the loop then sum to that:

```
s = 0
for i in range(len(number)):
    length = length - 1
    """Computes the sum for each digit"""
    s += number[i] * (int(base) ^ length)
```

but you are not converting `number[i]` to an actual numeric value there yet.

You'll want a mapping from 'digit' to numerical value here:

```
digits = {c: i for i, c in enumerate('0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')}
```

This creates a dictionary mapping from string digit to numerical value, so `'7'` maps to `7` and `f` maps to 15, etc. giving you a mapping all the way up to base 36.

Now you can use `digits` to map from string digit to numerical value:

```
s = 0
base = int(base)
for i, digit in enumerate(reversed(number.lower())):
    s += digits[digit] * (base ** i)
```

I reversed the processing of the digits here; much easier to go from smaller to larger. `enumerate()` gives us an index count, and you can loop *directly* over `number` to yield characters, rather than use `range()` and index into `number`. I lowercase `number` so that `a` and `A` both mean `10` in bases that go that high.

This then can be turned into a one-liner in a function:

```
digits = {c: i for i, c in enumerate('0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')}

def parse_number(number, base):
    return sum(digits[digit] * (base ** i)
               for i, digit in enumerate(reversed(number.lower())))

print(parse_number(number, int(base)))
```

Comment: I changed it to ** but it gives me 11 as answer for any number. Any help please?

Answer (score 2):

This will convert from any base, provided base <= 36, to any base (same restriction), with a default output base of 10

```py
def changebase(n, base=10, to=10):
    '''
    params:
      n     - number to convert
      base  - current base of number
      to    - desired base, must be <= 36
    '''
    # check that bases are <= 36
    if to > 36 or base > 36:
        raise ValueError('max base is 36')

    # convert to base 10
    n = int(str(n),base)
    positive = n >= 0

    # return if base 10 is desired
    if to == 10:
        return str(n)

    # convert to new base
    n = abs(n)
    num = []
    handle_digit = lambda i: str(i) if i < 10 else chr(i+55)
    while n > 0:
        num.insert(0, handle_digit(n % to))
        n = n // to

    # return string value of n in new base
    return ''.join(num) if positive else '-' + ''.join(num)
```

Comment: Works great. You might wanna add a check for if n=0 because currently it returns an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

To find the value for any digit, you need to know not only its position and base, but the set and ordering of the possible digits. In the code:

```
s = number[i] * (int(base) ^ length)
```

I don't see a conversion from the character representation of a digit `number[i]` to a numeric value. The line after it is even odder, as you just double `s`, rather than collecting a sum of values.

(As a side note, Python's `int` type already handles bases from 2 to 36.)

Just because the exercise is fun, here's a slightly different approach:

```
import string

number = input("Enter a number: ")
base = int(input("Enter the base: "))
digits = (string.digits+string.ascii_lowercase)[:base]

result = 0
for digit in number.lower():
    result = result*base + digits.index(digit)

print(result)
```

Comment: Sure `int()` already does this, but then the OP wouldn't have a coding exercise anymore. :-P