# How to convert the given number into base7 representation using the process of recursion?

Tags: python

The program defines base7() function.
In the main program it takes the input integer and sends tit to the Base7() function.
The Base7() function contains base and recursive criterion.

how to  convert integer to a base7

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your code.

Comment: where is the Program and main? i guess u forgot to write code.
If it's an assignment question, please don't post here. Stack overflow is not for Ur assignments

Comment: Did you search for similar questions here, like [Base Converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26929227/base-converter-in-python) ? Or search the web and find [LeetCode #504. Base 7. Environment: Python 3.7 | by Fatboy Slim | Medium](https://donic0211.medium.com/leetcode-504-base-7-3e9ff8a22fd2)

Comment: There is no [tag:python] in this question.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to figure the last digit, then return the result of the rest of the digits (by recursing on your function) followed by the last digit.  Unless...  There is no 'rest', in which case just return the last digit.

```
def base7(n: int) -> str:
    frac = n % 7
    rest = n // 7
    return base7(rest) + str(frac) if rest else str(frac)
```

Taking a valid comment on board...

A recursive method is generally to reduce the problem and re-apply your function to the reduced problem, remembering to add a terminating condition (or it'll never return its answer).  In this case, calculate the last digit then re-apply the function to the remaining number that lies to the left of that digit.  Reduce and conquer.

The above code does this, but it does return a string - mainly as it gives clearer code.  To return an 'int' means simply a change to the last line:

```
def base7(n: int) -> int:
    frac = n % 7
    rest = n // 7
    return base7(rest) * 10 + frac if rest else frac
```

Comment: "like an assignment though" .. instead of **mainly code with few explanation** wouldn't it be better to give pseudo-code or guide about number bases or recursion first. "Teach how to fish instead feeding." [How do I ask and answer homework questions? - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Awesome explanation of recursive ("Reduce and Conquer"), you also adjusted the function name. Also valid to leave some debugging tasks (+, conv) as final assignment to the learner ️

Comment: Oh willies - that's what I get for not testing the code before posting...! :)

Answer (score 0):

#### What means base-7 ?

See Base Number, Number Systems or [Radix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix).

For example represent decimal `10` in:

- **base-2** is *binary*: use only 2 digits per position (0-1) to represent the number, e.g. bin `1010`
- **base-8** is *octal*: use only 8 digits per position (0-7) to represent the number, e.g. oct `12`
- **base-10** is *decimal*: use only 10 digits per position (0-9) to represent the number, e.g. dec `10`

Your desired is:

- **base-7** is *septimal*: use only 7 digits per position (0-6) to represent the number, e.g. sept `13`

Explained: First digit `1` because 10 is divisible by 7 for 1 time (quotient). The remainder of 3 is the last digit (10 = 7 + 3).

#### See also

- [[LeetCode]#504. Base 7. Environment: Python 3.7 | by Fatboy Slim | Medium](https://donic0211.medium.com/leetcode-504-base-7-3e9ff8a22fd2)

Answer (score -2):

```
def base7(n: int) -> str:
    if n == 0:
        return ""
    quotient, remainder = divmod(n, 7)
    return base7(quotient) + str(remainder)
```

Comment: Please format code properly. and explain your code to beginners, especially `divmod`.

Comment: Also note that this will return "" when called with n==0 rather than "0"

To format code, indent it with four spaces.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).